# 404 when clicking "edit question" while another user has meanwhile proposal an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

- While reading a question that didn't have any suggested edits, I clicked "edit"
- Got a 404 page
- Reloaded the question, it now appeared with edit(0) so someone must have proposed an edit while I was viewing it

So I guess it's good it did not let me edit it, but it shouldn't have shown a 404...

Comment: (Confirmed on meta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this in a roundabout way.

We now allow users to edit a suggested edit (new improve button) ... so that fixes the error issue.